# What are the implications of not having a manifest file in my Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I've been having some strange problems in my build where some .exe are not found in the folder `$(OutputPath)\app.publish`.

The problem occurs during execution of GenerateManifest target. I've been thinking about removing the manifest generation to get rid of this but I am not sure about the implications.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whick kind of problems are you having there? Manifest tells to system what the Authorization/Permission Level the app must run (see UAC) and in which type of Windows system.

Comment: It says it cannot find the built .exe in the folder  $(OutputPath)\app.publish. After I build again, the problem is gone.

Comment: It´s not a MANIFEST problem. Sometimes VS2013 does the same thing and I believe it´s related to some internal processing or an extension activity (like Reasharper for instance). It´s not related to the MANIFEST file.